# How to insert user details in WordPress using MySQL

Tags: wordpress

hi I am writing migration script for Wordpress.

I am stucked on inserting details in wordpress using sql statements.

Insert values in wp_users are not reflection in admin panel. (account are there but total account is not matching )

how to fix this prob ?
my current query is

```
insert into wp_users (user_login,user_nicename,user_email,user_registered,user_status,display_name,user_pass) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Hi, have you looked at wp_usermeta table. There are some other details stored for particular user.

Comment: whate are the necessary fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are user_id, meta_key and meta_value. If you need to set nickname of any user, insert `user_id` for that user, "nickname" and `metakey`, and actual value, for example "vidya" in `meta_value`,

insert into wp_usermeta set `user_id` = 10, `meta_key` = 'nickname', `meta_value` = 'vidya';